# How do you create a persistent Ubuntu USB on a Mac that will boot to a Mac or PC

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mac, boot, usb

Hello I have actually successfully created a Ubuntu USB using unetbootin, however it is not persistent and will not boot on a mac.  If anyone has any suggestions for a different application for creating this drive please let me know (it must run on a Mac).  Or, if anyone has any suggestions on how to edit the .iso file so it boots from a Mac and is persistent, that would be great too.  I am running OSX Mavericks so the application would have to run on Mavericks too.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might try asking this question on askubuntu.com.

Comment: Thx I did, but if anyone knows the answer please let me know